# How to fix "Bad interface file" during installation of package with stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install stylish-haskell package with

```
stack install stylish-haskell
```

but I get "Bad interface file" error.

Here's log of installation:

```
ptparse-applicative-0.14.3.0.log
Configuring optparse-applicative-0.14.3.0...
Preprocessing library for optparse-applicative-0.14.3.0..
Building library for optparse-applicative-0.14.3.0..
[ 1 of 16] Compiling Options.Applicative.Help.Levenshtein ( Options/Applicative/Help/Levenshtein.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Options/Applicative/Help/Levenshtein.o )
[ 2 of 16] Compiling Options.Applicative.Help.Pretty ( Options/Applicative/Help/Pretty.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Options/Applicative/Help/Pretty.o )
Options/Applicative/Help/Pretty.hs:6:1: error:
    Bad interface file: /home/george/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/lts-13.21/8.6.5/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.6.5/ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.2-FavuR50rvZs3UXCXkBzL8N/Text/PrettyPrint/ANSI/Leijen.hi
        Data.Binary.getPrim: end of file
  |
6 | import Text.PrettyPrint.ANSI.Leijen hiding ((<$>), (<>), columns)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: On log/error formatting, I suggest just using a normal code block -- it is the most readable option.

Comment: [Stack issue #3248](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3248) seems relevant. I suggest trying the `stack exec ghc-pkg unregister` workaround mentioned in the first post there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751851/duplode) has pointed out, this is likely a case of [Stack issue #3248](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3248). A workaround is `stack exec ghc-pkg unregister ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8.2` followed by `stack build`, which will trigger a reinstall of the affected package.

Comment: I have edited the answer to directly mention the workaround. Please edit it if what I have added doesn't match what you have actually done.