# XMonad crashing: how to do proper build with Stack and custom build script?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, xmonad

OS: linux gentoo 6.0.9

I am attempting to build a custom version of XMonad using Stack and a build script I wrote, which is closely based on [this one here](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad-testing/blob/master/build-scripts/build-with-stack.sh).

`build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
SRC_DIR=$HOME/.config/xmonad
EXE_DIR=$HOME/.local/bin
EXE_NAME=xmonad
######################
unset STACK_YAML
cd $SRC_DIR
stack build 2>.log
ln -f -T $(stack exec -- which $EXE_NAME) $EXE_DIR/$EXE_NAME 2>.log
rm ./src/$EXE_NAME.hi ./src/$EXE_NAME.o 2>/dev/null
```

The `stack build` invocation above fails to compile a module that I wrote called `Prompt.Man` (not to be confused by `XMonad.Prompt.Man`, which I did not write) that previously compiled fine, and I do not understand the GHC error at all; when I try looking at the file the error references (`XMonad/Actions/OnScreen.dyn_hi`), it is a binary.

`.log`:

```
Building executable 'xmonad-vem:xmobar'.
Other executables with the same name might be overwritten: 'xmobar:xmobar'.

Building executable 'xmonad-vem:xmonad'.
Other executables with the same name might be overwritten: 'xmonad:xmonad'.

Building all executables for `xmonad-vem' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
xmonad-vem> configure (exe)
xmonad-vem> Configuring xmonad-vem-0.3...
xmonad-vem> build (exe)
xmonad-vem> Preprocessing executable 'xmobar' for xmonad-vem-0.3..
xmonad-vem> Building executable 'xmobar' for xmonad-vem-0.3..
xmonad-vem> [9 of 9] Compiling Prompt.Man
xmonad-vem> 
xmonad-vem> /home/myuser/.config/xmonad/src/Prompt/Man.hs:9:1: error:
xmonad-vem>     Bad interface file: /home/myuser/.config/xmonad/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/11f8cebbee3588011a80cb3a0acfb83ab68c1e233a64bf2f944fbcae91e1b2fb/8.10.6/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.10.6/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0-KtuI6PQ7yCQKkNv0hd26Wj/XMonad/Actions/OnScreen.dyn_hi
xmonad-vem>         Something is amiss; requested module  xmonad-contrib-0.17.0:XMonad.Actions.OnScreen differs from name found in the interface file xmonad-contrib-0.17.0-Jq55vblrWW56gRIiMssDFv:XMonad.Actions.OnScreen (if these names look the same, try again with -dppr-debug)
xmonad-vem>   |
xmonad-vem> 9 | import XMonad.Actions.OnScreen (onlyOnScreen)
xmonad-vem>   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

--  While building package xmonad-vem-0.3 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      /home/myuser/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.2.1.0_ghc-8.10.6 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0 build exe:xmobar exe:xmonad --ghc-options ""
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Adding the flag `-dppr-debug` to `ghc-opts` in `package.yaml` as suggested by GHC yields the exact same error message upon attempt to rebuild.

I've also tried deleting my `.stack` and `.stack-work` directories and then re-running as a hopeless attempt to see if that fixes anything, to no avail.

What is causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

#### Additional files

`stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-18.7
packages:
  - .
  - /var/cache/distfiles/xmobar-0.44.1
  - /var/cache/distfiles/xmonad-0.17.0
  - /var/cache/distfiles/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0
extra-deps: []
flags:
  xmobar:
    with_xpm: false
    with_threaded: false
    with_xft: true
    with_rtsopts: false
    with_alsa: true
    with_mpd: false
    with_weather: false
    with_dbus: false
    with_mpris: false
    with_inotify: false
    with_nl80211: false
    with_iwlib: false
    with_datezone: false
    with_uvmeter: false
    with_kraken: false
arch: x86_64
```

`/var/cache/distfiles/` is where I have specific versions of the source code for xmonad, xmonad-contrib, and xmobar saved.

`package.yaml`:

```
name: xmonad-vem
version: 0.3

ghc-options: -Wall -Wcompat -Wincomplete-record-updates -Wincomplete-uni-patterns -Wredundant-constraints -O2 -j -dynamic

dependencies:
  - base
  - containers
  - directory
  - filepath
  - process
  - regex-tdfa
  - utf8-string
  - unix
  - xmobar
  - xmonad >= 0.17
  - xmonad-contrib >= 0.17

source-dirs:
  - src

executables:
  xmonad:
    main: xmonad.hs
    dependencies:
      - xmonad
      - X11 >= 1.10
  xmobar:
    main: xmobar.hs
    dependencies:
      - xmobar
```

### UPDATE #1

At the request of a comment saying that the issue is with the globally-installed version of `xmonad-contrib-0.17.0`, I tried `stack exec ghc-pkg unregister xmonad-contrib-0.17.0 && stack build`, which now compiles but immediately crashes at runtime with the following error:

```
discover_other_daemon: 0/home/myuser/.local/bin/xmonad: error while loading shared libraries: libHSxmonad-contrib-0.17.0-Jq55vblrWW56gRIiMssDFv-ghc8.10.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

### UPDATE #2

I figured part of this out thanks to a comment; I needed to update my `stack.yaml` to not include the local versions of xmonad, xmonad-contrib, and xmobar and let Stack just fetch them for me:

`stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-18.7
packages:
  - .
extra-deps:
  - xmonad-0.17.0
  - xmonad-contrib-0.17.0
  - xmobar-0.44.1
  xmobar:
    with_xpm: false
    with_threaded: false
    with_xft: true
    with_rtsopts: false
    with_alsa: true
    with_mpd: false
    with_weather: false
    with_dbus: false
    with_mpris: false
    with_inotify: false
    with_nl80211: false
    with_iwlib: false
    with_datezone: false
    with_uvmeter: false
    with_kraken: false
arch: x86_64
```

...and slightly edit the build script:
`build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
SRC_DIR=$HOME/.config/xmonad
EXE_DIR=$HOME/.local/bin
EXE_NAME_XMONAD=xmonad
EXE_NAME_XMOBAR=xmobar
######################
unset STACK_YAML
cd $SRC_DIR
stack build 2>.log
ln -f -T $(stack exec -- which $EXE_NAME_XMONAD) $EXE_DIR/$EXE_NAME_XMONAD 2>.log
ln -f -T $(stack exec -- which $EXE_NAME_XMOBAR) $EXE_DIR/$EXE_NAME_XMOBAR 2>.log
rm ./src/$EXE_NAME_XMONAD.hi ./src/$EXE_NAME_XMONAD.o ./src/$EXE_NAME_XMOBAR.hi ./src/$EXE_NAME_XMOBAR.o 2>/dev/null
```

And I still get a similar runtime error after executing `build.sh` and trying to run the new `xmonad` and `xmobar` from `/home/myuser/.local/bin` on X server:

```
discover_other_daemon: 0XMonad is recompiling and replacing itself with another XMonad process because the current process is called "xmonad" but the compiled configuration should be called "xmonad-x86_64-linux"
XMonad will use build script at "/home/myuser/.config/xmonad/build" to recompile.
XMonad recompiling because a custom build script is being used.
XMonad recompilation process exited with success!
/home/myuser/.cache/xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux: error while loading shared libraries: libHSxmonad-contrib-0.17.0-KtuI6PQ7yCQKkNv0hd26Wj-ghc8.10.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: I see that one of the paths says `linux`. I was suspecting an issue with case insensitivity on MacOS. What happens when you add `-dppr-debug` to the `ghc-options` for `xmonad-vem` as suggested in the error message?

Comment: It's weird that there are two different hashes for `xmonad-contrib` involved: `KtuI6PQ7yCQKkNv0hd26Wj` and `Jq55vblrWW56gRIiMssDFv`. No idea what could be the reason though. I'd probably report it at https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues.

Comment: @sjakobi OS is Linux. I edited the post to include that info as well as the result of trying `-dppr-debug`

Comment: What's `/var/cache/distfiles/`? Stack would normally find packages from it's own resolver. Since you appear to have two different `xmonad-contrib`s involved (judging by the two different hashes), could something you're doing be depending on `xomand-contrib` from the resolver and something else depending on the `xmonad-contrib` you have in `/var/cache/distfiles/`?

Comment: could you include the `package.yaml` file?. It looks to me like you have two different versions of xmonad-contrib-0.17.0 and `stack` is confused about it.

Comment: Also, following the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368459/how-to-fix-bad-interface-file-during-installation-of-package-with-stack) answer It maybe possible the you have installed `xmonad-contrib` globally, but your current project is pointing to a different local version in `var/cache/...`. They suggest to unregister the global package.  `stack exec ghc-pkg unregister xmonad-contrib-0.17.0` and then `stack build`

Comment: @lsmor indeed `/var/cache/distfiles/` is where source code for specific versions of these software are installed. More details added in a post edit called *UPDATE #1*

Comment: Could you check if `/home/myuser/.local/bin/xmonad` is update when you build it? I'm not understanding the usage of a custom build script. When you create the hard link what does `stack exec -- which $EXE_NAME_XMONAD` returns? Notice that `stack build` will create an executable only visible by `stack` under `.stack-work` folder (maybe the `unset STACK_YAML` changes this behavior... don't know).

Comment: also, notice that your executable is named `xmonad` instead of `xmonad-x86_64-linux`. I am trying to find the docs about these two, but AFAIK `xmonad` executable is sort of the launcher for `xmonad-x86_64-linux` which is the executable for your own configuration. Are you force to use a custom build script?

Comment: @lsmor The compiling and file linking is working correctly and the executable in my local bin is the correct one (the one from `.stack-work` bin). But good to know about the XMonad compilation behavior. I am probably invoking my build script incorrectly. Right now, I just directly call it via `./build.sh`. I will set it up differently and try invoking `$HOME/.local/bin/xmonad --recompile` instead. I'll update you with my results soon... It takes me some time to do this and post my results here because I am doing it without a display server setup, as X/XMonad is what I usually use for that.

Comment: @lsmor Update: solved. What you said about `xmonad` binary being the launcher for `xmonad-x86_64-linux` made me realize that my build script needed to accept an argument and link to that, rather than my bin. Added an answer with further explanation below. Thanks so much! I am currently typing this from my working display manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. This is what I had to do:

#### #1

Use the following as my starting point for the Stack config.

`stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-18.7
packages:
  - .
extra-deps:
  - xmonad-0.17.0
  - xmonad-contrib-0.17.0
  - xmobar-0.44.1
  xmobar:
    with_xpm: false
    with_threaded: false
    with_xft: true
    with_rtsopts: false
    with_alsa: true
    with_mpd: false
    with_weather: false
    with_dbus: false
    with_mpris: false
    with_inotify: false
    with_nl80211: false
    with_iwlib: false
    with_datezone: false
    with_uvmeter: false
    with_kraken: false
arch: x86_64
```

`package.yaml`:

```
name: xmonad-vem
version: 0.3

ghc-options: -Wall -Wcompat -Wincomplete-record-updates -Wincomplete-uni-patterns -Wredundant-constraints -O2 -j -dynamic

dependencies:
  - base
  - containers
  - directory
  - filepath
  - process
  - regex-tdfa
  - utf8-string
  - unix
  - xmobar
  - xmonad >= 0.17
  - xmonad-contrib >= 0.17

source-dirs:
  - src

executables:
  xmonad:
    main: xmonad.hs
    dependencies:
      - xmonad
      - X11 >= 1.10
  xmobar:
    main: xmobar.hs
    dependencies:
      - xmobar
```

###### Explanation

Needed to make sure Stack pulls in as dependencies the versions of xmonad, xmonad-contrib, and xmobar that I want to use as a starting point, as specified by the dependencies in `package.yaml`; as opposed to trying to use the globally installed versions I have on my machine.

#### #2

Update my `build` script to the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
SRC_DIR=$HOME/.config/xmonad
EXE_NAME=xmonad
unset STACK_YAML
FAIL=0
cd $SRC_DIR
stack build 2>.log || FAIL=1
ln -f -T $(stack exec -- which $EXE_NAME) $1 2>.log || FAIL=2
rm ./src/*.hi ./src/*.o 2>/dev/null
exit $FAIL
```

then invoking `xmonad --recompile && startx` works how it should.

###### Explanation

The recompiling process for XMonad does more than what my build script did. In mine, I was simply linking the compiled `xmonad` and `xmobar` binaries directly to my local bin and exiting, then invoking `./build` on the command line to recompile xmonad; however, calling the build script via `xmonad --recompile` actually passes an argument to `./build` and is supposed to link the binaries to that.

Thanks to @lsmor for pointing this out.

Comment: Glad you find a solution!. When you said you run the script manually I suspected that's the wrong thing to do haha. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Core.hs#L662) `xmonad --recompile` will run the `build` script passing the binary path (your personal configuration binary) as an argument to the script. It doesn't do anything else.

Comment: By the way, apparently `xmonad` looks for an script called `build` not `build.sh` but I guess I am missing something since it works for you

Comment: @lsmor Oh yeah I put  `build.sh` just to clarify the script type in the post. I corrected it in the answer now